# Regex match for string between / and .jsp

Tags: javascript, regex

If I do regex match for

```
str = "/mypage/account/info.jsp"
str.match('\/.*\.jsp')
```

I get entire string but I want to grab only "info"

How can I accomplish using only regex?

Comment: Try [`[^\/\s]+(?=\.jsp$)`](https://regex101.com/r/la4sQ0/1/)

Comment: @HaoWu No need of escaping `/` in character class.

Comment: @decpk Oh, you're right. But I'll keep it in case OP wants to use regex literal.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get the text after the last `/`

```
/[^/]*$/
```

and then get the desired result using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const str = "/mypage/account/info.jsp";
const match = str.match(/[^/]*$/);

const result = match && match[0].split(".")[0];
console.log(result);
```

only regex

```js
const str = "/mypage/account/info.jsp";
const match = str.match(/[^/]+(?=\.jsp$)/);

console.log(match[0]);
```